# chrome rdp for google cloud platform does not work

Tags: windows, rdp

I signed up for cloud computing with google.
I created a windows 2008 server instance.
When I click on the RDP button, I get an error that says Your credentials did not work.  The post does not allow me to add images as I do not have atleast 10 posts.

At first I thought I am entering the wrong username/password, so I dropped the instance and re-created it.
I wrote down the username/password.
I know I am entering the username/password correctly.

I also deleted the certificate (under advance settings in rdp).

Please let me know what am I missing

Thanks
Munish